# Django not printing post request

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm learning Django and creating my website...
Created and basic HTML contact form and to check if it is working I've added an print option on form submission(method==post) but

after I submit the form, on terminal prints nothing

below are my codes 
Thank you For your time

***views.py***

```
def contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ("we are done")

    return render(request,"news/Home/Homepage.html")
```

_____models.py_______

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    msg=models.TextField()
```

____my html contact form__________

```
<form class="grid-form" method="post" action="/">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-control narrow">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control narrow">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email">

    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input value="Send Message" type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("" , views.index),
    path("league",views.index2),
    path("pl",views.index3),
    path("ptable", views.index4),
    path("fs", views.index5),
    path("latest", views.index6),
    path("history", views.index7)
]
```

Comment: Did you try put the url on <form action="/myurl" method="post">?

Comment: "/ " is my home page on wich I'm submitting my form also my form is on home page

Comment: Your view function named _contact_ is never called, so nothing is printed. You have to add a url in the _urls.py_, referring to this view function, and put it in the _action_ attribute of the form tag.

Comment: @OmidRezaAbbasi can u tell how exactly to do so

Comment: @OmidRezaAbbasi THANKS GOT IT!!

Answer (score 0):

Give path in your action in the form:

```
<form class="grid-form" method="post" action="/">
```

There, should be `action` attribute should correspond to the path which will trigger `contact` function in `views.py`.

### EDIT

Your urls.py does not contain any url where you could send the request from form. As, I already mentioned about the `action`, your `home` directory is not in `index` function. So, you have to add a path to send request. Like:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("" , views.index),
    path("contact" , views.contact, name="contact"),    # Here
    path("league",views.index2),
    path("pl",views.index3),
    path("ptable", views.index4),
    path("fs", views.index5),
    path("latest", views.index6),
    path("history", views.index7)
]
```

And, you have to send the form to that path `www.example.com/contact`. Like:

```
<form class="grid-form" method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
```

*Note:- I gave the action value according to the name, which is great practice. So, lets start giving name in the url. But, the way you did is also fine.

Comment: "/" corresponds to  my homepage on which I am submitting my form

Comment: Show us urls.py

Comment: added urls.py of my app indexes are different pages